# Are my tables normalized with 2NF?

Tags: database-design

**The question:** is my database in second normal form?

What will happen if I do not normalize my database?

[image]

I know we need some data to check normal forms but column names are giving you data to answer my question !

Comment: @MitchWheat:  They don't die, they manifest themselves as hellhounds whenever you need to add a new, database-intense feature.

Comment: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Comment: Column names & relation schemas do not suffice to assess normal forms.  What's needed in addition are the applicable functional dependencies.  Without those specced out, the only thing we can do is assume the only FDs are those that derive from the keys, and then any schema is at least in 3NF by definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No one can tell you with certainty whether your database satisfies 2NF without knowing what dependencies it is supposed to satisfy.

Unless this is an academic exercise you don't need to worry too much about 2NF specifically.List out the dependencies yourself and make sure all the determinants are superkeys in your database. That way you have satisfied BCNF and very probably 5NF as well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes your data is in 2nf (The data base also satisfies 3nf norms). If you do not normalize your data base then it may contain redundant data (duplicate data across tables)and this may result  in incorrect data in case you update the same record in one table and dose not update that duplicate record in another table. For example in your case if you put url in votes table and user_visited table instead of url_id.Then in case of any update in url you need to update all the tables that has the url and if you fail to do so then the data is corrupted. And if your tables are normalized as they are here, you need to update only one table urls. The another point is that to get the votes data you will need to make a join with urls table to get the url and if the data is huge then the select operation with join will take time.So to avoid this some times normalization is compromised  and that is called DeNormalization.